# How can I setup Nginx Proxy Buffering with Gunicorn over Amazon EC2?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

My Django app is hosted up on Amazon EC2. Gunicorn runs on the same machine and serves all the dynamic content that I have. There is no static content. I have TWO of these machines (both machines are running Ubuntu 11.04 on a micro instance. These are easy to scale horizontally) and I have a ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) sitting in front of both of these servers.

For the sake of example, the external ip of both of these gunicorn/django ubuntu machines is:

```
12.34.567.12:8000 & 21:43:765:21:8000 (gunicorn runs on port 8000).
```

If I were to put either of these addresses into my browser, I can interact with my server and send/retrieve data.

When I place an ELB infront of these two machines, the new address I can use to interact with BOTH DJANGO/GUNICORN SERVERS is:

```
dualstack.myloadbalancer-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8000
```

When I've been reading a lot of resources across the internet and many suggested having an NGINX box sitting in front the Django app servers behind the ELB to buffer requests for slow clients. I think this would be a good feature to have since I don't want to lose any requests. The diagram below will explain is more clearly:

[image]

Just like the diagram above, how can I configure the nginx box sitting in front of the django app/gunicorn servers to act as a reverse proxy so that it can buffer requests for slow clients? (this way, instead of timing out, it keeps the request without losing it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the nginx [HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) I believe.
You define a upstream in nginx

```
upstream webservers {
    server 12.34.567.12:8000;
    server 21.43.765.21:8000;
}
```

And then forward requests via proxy_pass to the upstream.

```
server {
    listen 443; //Port you want nginx to listen on
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 330;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://webservers ;
     }
}
```

And unless I'm mistaken the HttpProxyModule buffers the entire request before passing it on. 
This may break some items that require streaming or interaction during this process but that's a limit you face.

My nginx is a bit rusty so it might not work but it should be something along these lines

Comment: your answer seems promising. So now my question is, do I now point my clients to the nginx server (let's say the external ip of the nginx server is 10.12.13.22)? since nginx is buffering requests from 12.34.567.12:8000 and 21.43.765.21:8000 would I point them to 10.12.13.22:8000 instead?

Comment: In the example the end point would be 10.12.13.22:443 because it's selected with the `listen` directive. However this can be any port you want.

Comment: yes, it did, I forgot to accept your answer! thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want nginx sitting in front of gunicorn.  It is a common setup and you can find a lot of resources to help you get started.  I like this tutorial: http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/, which will also walk you through supervisord and setting up a virtualenv.

Comment: I editing my question to make it more clearer. I'm not quite familiar with nginx or it's configuration. From what I know, people say it's a really good proxy buffer for nginx. So instead of timing out slow connections, it keeps them and buffers the data they are requesting. I have 3 gunicorn workers running on each machine. How would I configure nginx to play well with this setup? What would be the appropriate fields and values I would use to configure nginx? Your expertise is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to host on EC2 with Ubuntu server than these are some good tutorials apart from the one mentioned by Nathan.

- http://ijcdigital.com/blog/django-gunicorn-and-nginx-setup/
  This one is setting up Nginx and Gunicorn in Ubuntu.
- http://ydevel.tumblr.com/post/22850778860/configuring-an-https-site-with-django-on-nginx
  This one is for setting up with Https Configurations also.
- http://adrian.org.ar/automatic-setup-of-django-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ec2/ This one is quite interesting because it explains How to install Nginx with Gunicorn in EC2 using Bellatrix(a nice library over boto). Do go through this one atleast once. Its very good

Best Of Luck with your deployment. If you find the answer helpful do accept the answer

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clearer. Instead of running nginx on the same machines as the app servers, wouldn't it be more ideal to run it on a separate machine so that it can buffer requests? All of my content is dynamic, none of it is static. The only use I would have for nginx is just proxy buffering.